# Underscore template throwing variable not defined error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I've watched some videos on the topic of backbone js. This is an example straight from the video. It is from 2012, so I'm thinking backbone rules/library have changed, but I can't figure out why this does not work at the moment. In the video, the person shows it running in the JS Fiddle, but I can't get it to work. (I've included the necessary libraries in JS Fiddle, i.e. underscore, backbone and jQuery)

```js
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:'body',
  render: function () {
   var data = { lat: -27, lon: 153 };
    this.$el.html(_.template('<%= lat %> <%= lon%>', data));
    return this;
  }
});

var v = new V();

v.render();
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You used to be able to parse and fill in an Underscore template in one go like this:

```
var html = _.template(template_string, data);
```

But as of Underscore 1.7.0, the second argument to [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) contains template options:

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [settings])`
>
> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering. [...] The **settings** argument should be a hash containing any `_.templateSettings` that should be overridden.

You have to compile the template using `_.template` and then execute the returned function to get your filled in template:

```
var tmpl = _.template(template_string);
var html = tmpl(data);

// or as a one-liner, note where all the parentheses are
var html = _.template(template_string)(data);
```

In your case, it would look something like this:

```js
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:'body',
  render: function () {
    var data = { lat: -27, lon: 153 };
    var tmpl = _.template('<%= lat %> <%= lon %>');
    this.$el.html(tmpl(data));
    return this;
  }
});

var v = new V();

v.render();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful

1: If you have more then one template or sometime you are using external template so it can be useful for you inside method you can write reusable code

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'body',
    temp: function (str) {

        // reusable code
        return _.template(str);
    },
    render: function () {
        var data = { lat: -27, lon: 153 };

        // calling your view method temp        
        var tmpl = this.temp('<%= lat %> <%= lon %>');
        this.$el.html(tmpl(data));

        return this;
    }
});

var v = new V();
v.render();
```