# Backbone Inline HTML Templates versus External Templating

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

My backbone app currently has inline HTML for its templates as follows:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header></header>
    <nav></nav>
        <div id="pagecontent"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>


        <!-- Featured Articles/Homepage Template -->
<script type="text/template" id="featuredarticles">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepagecontent.css" />
    <section id="banner"></section>
        <aside>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </aside>
        <section id="main"></section>
        <section id="opinion">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </section>
        <section id="travel">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </section>
</script>

    <!-- Content Articles Template -->
    <script type="text/template" id="contentarticles">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/categorypagecontent.css" />
        <section id="main"></section>
        <aside></aside>
    </script>

    <!-- Require.js reference -->
    <script src="/js/libs/require.js" data-main="/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

Can I / should I externalize the HTML instead. If so, how would I externalize this (i.e. using the View) so it is as follows:

```
        <!-- Featured Articles/Homepage Template -->
<script type="text/template" id="featuredarticles">
<!-- HTML rendered externally -->            
</script>

    <!-- Content Articles Template -->
    <script type="text/template" id="contentarticles">
    <!-- HTML rendered externally --> 
    </script>
```

Here is a snippet of how I render a template currently from a View:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'collections/bannerCollection', 'collections/featuredArticlesCollection', ], function (_, Backbone, bannerCollection, featuredArticlesCollection) {
var featuredArticlesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#pagecontent'),
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var template = _.template($('#featuredarticles').html(), {});
        that.$el.html(template);
return that;
    }
});

return featuredArticlesView;

});
```

I have been reading about partials, but need some guidance on best practice and if / how the inline HTML should be broken out.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the requirejs "text" module? https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: I just starting looking into that. I will take a closer look.

Comment: You can also precompile your Underscore templates to bits of JavaScript server-side. `t = _.template(x)` leaves you with a JavaScript function in `t` and the source can be found in `t.source`. BTW, that form of `_.template` is [no longer available, you have to compile and call separately now.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/4798630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found i while back this small snippet of a template manager (can't remember the author, sorry):

`TemplateManager = {
    templates: {}, // holds the templates cache
    get: function(id, callback){
        var template = this.templates[id];
        if (template) { // return the cached version if it exists
            callback(template);
        } else {
            var that = this;
            // fetch, cache and return the template
            $.get(id + ".html", function(template) { 
                that.templates[id] = template;
                callback(that.templates[id]);
            });
        }
    }
};`

It fetches the template file, caches it and calls a callback function after it was loaded, like this:

`TemplateManager.get('path/to/your/template', function(resp) {
    // resp is the template markup
    return this;
});`

Hope it helps.

UPDATE

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/411jgf78/1/

Comment: It does, would love to see a working example, but at least I can start searching for template management.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that it triggers a separate network (ajax) call for every view (granted only once each due to the caching).

Comment: How else can you load a remote template? If you extend on this idea, you could cache the template in localStorage, so it would be available on subsequent page refreshes and even sessions.