# passing model´s array to an underscore view

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to pass some models attibutes to my underscore view, however, for some reason I cannot find the right way to make it work, if some1 can point in the right direction, I would appreciated it.

```
 App.appModel = new App.Models.AppModel({
    "user" : data.user,
    "acls" : data.acls //acls is an array, which I need to pass to the view
 });
 App.appLogged = new App.Views.App({
    model : App.appModel
 });


 //My view
 App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
     render : function() {
       template = _.template( $('#Home').html(), {acls : this.model.toJSON }) ;
       this.$el.html(template);
     }
 });


//so In my view... I need a li with each acl
<script type="text/template" id="Home">
      <% _.each(acls, function(acl) { %>
        <li><%= acl.get(0)  %></li>
    <% }); %> 
</script>
```

It doens't throw any error... it just dont render it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pro tip:  add `<% debugger; %>` to underscore templates to set a breakpoint in them and see whats up

Comment: Note that this form of `_.template` [doesn't work anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863), you need to compile and fill-in the template in separate steps now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template compilation line:

```
//My view
 App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
     render : function() {
       template = _.template( $('#Home').html(), this.model.toJSON()) ;
       this.$el.html(template);
     }
 });
```

`model.toJSON` will produce an object with keys corresponding to the model attributes. In this case, it will already contain the key `acls`. What you were producing is

{
  acls: {
     acls: [],
     ...
  }
}

And what your template needs is:

{
  acls: [xxxx]
}

Normally it's useful to make a call to `console.log(this.model.toJSON())` on your render, to see what's going into your template.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like missing parens in the call `toJSON()`?

```
 //My view
 App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
     render : function() {
       template = _.template( $('#Home').html(), {acls : this.model.toJSON() }) ;
       this.$el.html(template);
     }
 });
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work, I think it is cause I'm passing a model with a few attributes, instead of acls alone. but If I make something like acls : this.model.permisos.toJSON(), it throws undefined.

Comment: @andresmijares25: Is `this.model` in your view a model or a collection? Why would a model have a `permisos` property? Wouldn't that be an *attribute* (i.e. `this.model.get('permisos')`)?