# How to get params in underscore template

Tags: underscore.js, marionette

I want to get "index" param in underscore template.

**// Template #blockNewsHome" in Item View**

```
<% if (index==0) { %>
<a href="#detailNews/<%= catCode %>/<%= linkSeo %>">
    <span><%= title %></span>
    <time><%= publishDate %></time>
</a>
<% } else { %>
    <span><%= title %></span>
<% } %>
```

**// View**

```
PageManager.module("PageApp.BlockNews", function(BlockNews, PageManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

    BlockNews.NewsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({ 
        template: "#blockNewsHome",
        tagName : "li",
    });

    BlockNews.NewsCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({           
        template: "#blockNewsHome",
        tagName: "ul",      
        childView: BlockNews.NewsView, 
        render : function () {
            var self = this;                    
            this.$('li').each(function(i, element){             
                _.template(this.template,{"index": i});                 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This shows too much code for just one line.. try only showing how you call the template _.template(....

Comment: Which version of Underscore are you using? The [`_.template(tmpl, data)` form is no longer supported.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863). Also, that `this.$('li').each(...)` doesn't do anything useful, you'd need to put the filled in template somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need "viewtemplatehelpers":

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/html">
  I <%= percent %>% think that <%= showMessage() %>
</script>
```

---

```
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#my-template",

  templateHelpers: function () {
    return {
      showMessage: function(){
        return this.name + " is the coolest!";
      },

      percent: this.model.get('decimal') * 100
    };
  }
});

var model = new Backbone.Model({
  name: "Backbone.Marionette",
  decimal: 1
});
var view = new MyView({
  model: model
});
```

Comment: [viewtemplatehelpers](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtemplatehelpers)