# my backbone sample is not working and giving with this.el.html is not a function

Tags: backbone.js

I am new bee to backbone and i am trying with a below sample

http://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/L3orucjm/

While loading i am getting this.el.html is not a function, let me know what is the cause of it.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="template">
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"></input>
<input type="button" name="Add" id="Add" value="Add"></input>

<div id="list"></div>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
NameModel = Backbone.Model.extend({


});
var nameModel = new NameModel();
nameModel.set('name','test');
alert(nameModel.get('name'));
NameView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"li",
    render: function(){
        var template=_.template("<%=name%>", nameModel.toJSON());
       return template;
    }
});
var nameView = new NameView();
NameViewList = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var template = _.template($("#template").html(), {});
        this.el.html(template);
    },
    events : {
        "click input#Add" :"addName",
    },
    addName : function() {
        var name = $("#Name").val();
        if (name.trim().length > 0) {
           //nameModel.set("name", name);
            $("#list").append(nameView.render());
        }
    }
});
var nameViewList = new NameViewList({el : $("div#container")});
```

Comment: you forgot  replacing <%=name%> with proper value in fiddle

Comment: I passed nameModel json as second parameter to template , so it will take care of it i guess. And one more thing is <%= name%> view will be called  on clicking of add button but the problem is on load,  which is giving el.html is not  a function in browser's console.

Comment: @muistooshort, I had an latest version of backbone 1.1.12 in fiddle. Please cross check.

Comment: Sorry @muistooshort. Its my bad now i had updated the libraries, still i am getting the same problem. Please check fiddle url in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numerous errors in your code. You know about one of them but not the others.

The one you know about is:

```
this.el.html(template);
```

A view's [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) is just a DOM node and that doesn't have an `html` function. The [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function you're trying to use is part of jQuery so you'd want to call it on [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) (which is just a cached version of `$(this.el)`):

```
this.$el.html(template);
```

Other problems:

1. Your fiddle is missing `var`s all over the place; don't say:

   ```
   NameModel = ...
   ```

   say:

   ```
   var NameModel
   ```

   to avoid accidental globals.
2. Your `NameView` is strange. It has `tagName: 'li'` so presumably it should be creating list elements but the `render` doesn't do anything with the view's `el`, it just returns a string of HTML that ends up inside a `<div>`. That `<div>` should be a `<ul>`:

   ```
   <ul id="list"></ul>
   ```

   A `render` function generally populates the view's `el` and, to allow chaining, returns `this`:

   ```
   render: function() {
       var template = _.template('<%= name %>');
       this.$el.html(template(nameModel.toJSON()));
       return this;
   }
   ```
3. You are using Underscore's `_.template` incorrectly. You used to be able to say:

   ```
   var h = _.template(template_source, data);
   ```

   to compile the template and fill it in in one step but [as of Underscore 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863), the second argument to `_.template` is an options object. Now you need to compile and fill in the template in separate steps:

   ```
   var t = _.template(template_source);
   var h = t(data);
   ```

   You'll see this change in the `render` above.
4. The way you're using your `NameView` is strange. Apparently you are trying to use one `NameView` to handle multiple names, this would work with your strange `NameView#render` implementation but it will fall apart once `NameView` has anything to do or once `NameView` is updated (as above) to be more conventional. You should create one `NameView` for each name you're displaying and each `NameView` should have its own `NameModel` as its `model` property. This would make `NameView#render` look like:

   ```
   render: function() {
       var template = _.template('<%= name %>');
       this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
       return this;
   }
   ```

   and `NameViewList#addName` would look like:

   ```
   addName: function() {
       var name = this.$("#Name").val();
       if(name.trim().length > 0) {
           var nameView = new NameView({
               model: new NameModel({ name: name })
           });
           this.$('#list').append(nameView.render().el);
       }
   }
   ```

   You'll note that we're using `NameView#render`'s new return value, this `x.append(v.render().el)` pattern is quite common and idiomatic in Backbone so it is a good practice. You should also notice that the search for `#list` is now limited to the view's `el` by using the view's [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) function; `this.$('#list')` is equivalent to `this.$el.find('#list')` and doing things this way helps you keep your views self-contained.

   In real life you'd probably put your `new NameModel({ name: name })` instances in a collection somewhere and events on that collection would trigger the creation of new `NameView`s.

Applying all that to your fiddle gives you this functional and more idiomatic version:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8x0ma9qo/

Comment: Many thanks to you for correcting my code. By your explanation and suggestions  i got a better idea on backbone .Thanks again.