# Underscore.js template IE9 / IE10 not returning right code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, underscore.js, template-engine, underscore.js-templating

I have this code in my js file

```
var selectedTagElement = _.template('$("#selected_tag_item_template").html()', item = { tag: label, value: value });
$('#wrapper_id').append(selectedTagElement);
```

and this in my html file

```
    <script type="text/template" id="selected_tag_item_template">
      <div class="tag_item selected js-selected_tag_item" 
           data-tag-value="<%= item.value %>" 
           data-tag-label="<%= item.tag %>"><%= item.tag %>
      </div>
    </script>
```

Everything is working fine in all browser but IE9 and IE10. If it try

```
console.log(selectedTagElement)
```

all i get is

```
LOG: function(n){return o.call(this,n,m)}
```

and if i try to print the item variables in my html file, like this

```
<%= item %>
```

i get this

```
function item() { [native code] }
```

What's going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're getting from:

```
console.log(selectedTagElement)
```

indicates that `selectedTagElement` is a function. You used to be able to compile and fill in a template in one step but that [stopped working in Underscore 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863).

You need to start building your `selectedTagElement` in two steps:

1. Compile the template to a function using `_.template`.
2. Run that function with the desired data to get your HTML.

So you want to be saying this:

```
var t = _.template($('#selected_tag_item_template').html());
var selectedTagElement = t({ item: { tag: label, value: value } });
```

That should work everywhere and matches the standard usage.

---

Your code works by accident where it works at all. I'm going to assume that `'$("#js_template").html()'` is just a typo because it doesn't make sense otherwise. Let us break up your code into something equivalent:

```
item = { tag: label, value: value };
var selectedTagElement = _.template('$("#js_template").html()', item);
$('#wrapper_id').append(selectedTagElement);
```

The first line creates a global `item` variable that holds the data you want to give to the template.

The second line will compile the template into a function and ignore the second `item` argument completely since it doesn't match any of [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template)'s options.

The third line hands a function to `[append`][2](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Normally you give `append` a string of HTML or a DOM node but you can also give it a function; when you give `append` a function, it runs the function and uses its return value as an HTML string. In non-IE browsers, the template function will get the `item` through your accidental global variable:

```
item = { tag: label, value: value }
```

but IE is using an `item` function (which is implemented with native code in the browser) from somewhere instead of using your `item` variable.

Comment: Yes sorry, #js_wrapper was a typo. I corrected it. Thanks, it works!