# Unexpected Token "." (period)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am starting to learn Backbone, but UnderscoreJS seems to be giving me some issues here. I am getting "Unexpected Token ." and I am not sure what that means. My JSON seems fine, so I am not expecting it to be a cause.

```js
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'http://welfordian.com/backbone/data/items'
});
var ToDoList = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  render: function() {
    var items = new Items();
    var elem = this;
    items.fetch({
      success: function(items) {
        var template = _.template($('#todo-list-content').html(), {
          items: items.models
        });
        elem.$el.html(template);
      }
    });
  }
});
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'completed': 'completed'
  }
});

var toDo = new ToDoList({});
var router = new Router();
router.on("route:index", function() {
  toDo.render();
});
Backbone.history.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div class="page"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="todo-list-content">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% ._each(items, function(item){ %>
        <tr>
          <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Comment: Also, you can't `_.template(tmpl, data)` anymore, you need to `t = _.template(tmpl); h = t(data)` now, see [**Backbone JS template example**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863).

Comment: Yeah, just had to figure this out myself. I should have came back earlier. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the `each` in the template is not correct.

Change

```
._each(items, function(item){
^^
```

to

```
_.each(items, function(item) {
```

Comment: Wow, rookie mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to notice