# Backbone templating using underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am learning backbone. I am facing an issue while using underscore.js for templating.
Following is the code.

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "body",
    render: function () {
        var data = {
            name: "MyName"
        };
        this.$el.html(_.template('<%= name %>', data));
        return this;
    }
});

var v = new V();
v.render();
```

Output:

```
result
```

It should be :

```
MyName
```

Code - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ronak_11/aykh92rp/2/)

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @mu is too short : golden badge on `backbone.js` oh man @___@

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke/evaluate the template with the `data` object as an argument.

Therefore it should be:

```
_.template('<%= name %>')(data);
```

or:

```
_.template('<%= name %>')({
  name: "MyName"
});
```

According to the [documentation for the `_.template` function](http://underscorejs.org/#template), you were passing the `data` object as an optional settings argument.

```
_.template(templateString, [settings])
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vxuoq71e/)

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "body",
    render: function () {
        var data = {
            name: "MyName"
        };
        this.$el.html(_.template('<%= name %>')(data));
    }
});

var v = new V();
v.render();
```

Output:

```
MyName
```

Comment: Note that [before Underscore 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863) you could say `_.template(tmpl, data)` to get HTML. There is still a lot of out of date code and tutorials in the wild.