# this.$el.off is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Previously this will work but I've update the underscore and backbone to the latest version, then I got error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$el.off is not a function
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmm770v8/

```
  SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
            this.el.html( template );
        },
        events: {
            "click input[type=button]": "doSearch"  
        },
        doSearch: function(){
            // Button clicked
            console.log(this.el.find('#search_input').val()); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You have several problems:

1. Your fiddle was using jQuery 1.5.2 which is ancient and used `bind`/`unbind` instead of `on`/`off`. Backbone expects a more recent version of jQuery which has `on` and `off` functions.
2. You're using [`this.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) where you mean [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el). `this.el` is just a plain old DOM node, `this.$el` is the cached `$(this.el)`.
3. The `var html = _.template(tmpl, data)` form of `_.template` [went away in Underscore 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863). You now need a two step process:

   ```
   var t = _.template(tmpl);
   var h = t(data);
   ```

   so your `render` should look more like this:

   ```
   render: function() {
       var template = _.template($("#search_template").html());
       this.$el.html(template({}));
   }
   ```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/L5z4agh4/