# Using jQuery.load to show a template in another template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I get **2 templates** : one for a form and one for a **row** for the result. This is how my view is. The form is displaying but when I have a **row**, I only get a static template of this row, I mean the `<% = key %>` doesn't work and the form disappear.

```
APP.FromFront = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#content"),
    events: {
        "click #addLink" : "addLink",
        "click .deleteLink" : "deleteLink"
    },
    template: _.template($('#content').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        this.bookmarks = new APP.BookmarksCollection();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.$el.load( "../../templates/form_template.html" ));
        this.bookmarks.each(function(bookmark) {
            var bookJSON = bookmark.toJSON();
            **//############ this is where it's doesn't work**
            var temp=_.template(this.$el.load( "../../templates/links_template.html" )); 
            $("#links").append(temp(bookJSON));
        },this);
    },
})
```

Comment: Why do you have an unused `template: _.template($('#content').html()),`? Why are you trying to load external file rather than using it? Do you understand how [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) works? Judging by code such as `this.$el.html( this.$el.load(url) )` I don't think so. Do you realize that our code is trying to fetch the same template over and over again? Even though browser might cache it, it isn't a good practice.  [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous. Please read the documentation first.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was used the template "template" when my template was in the index.html page. It's unused in this code.
I don't really want to load it but use it. I know how to do it if it's in the index.html but not in an other file.

Answer (score 2):

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous. You need to handle it that way. Also you should cache the template once it is loaded than trying to fetch the same template repeatedly. Try something as follows:

```js
APP.FromFront = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#content"),
  events: {
    "click #addLink": "addLink",
    "click .deleteLink": "deleteLink"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.bookmarks = new APP.BookmarksCollection();
    this.formTemplatePromise = $.get("../../templates/form_template.html");
    this.linkTemplatePromise = $.get("../../templates/links_template.html");
    $.when(this.formTemplatePromise, this.linkTemplatePromise)
     .then(function(formTemplate, linkTemplate) {
        this.formTemplate = _.template(formTemplate);
        this.linkTemplate = _.template(linkTemplate);
        this.render();
     }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.formTemplate( /* form data here? */ ));
    var links = [];
    this.bookmarks.each(function(bookmark) {
      // below code can be made a 1 liner, I split it for readability
      var bookJSON = bookmark.toJSON();
      var link = this.linkTemplate(bookJSON);
      links.push(link);
    }, this);
    // Single append instead of many for performance
    $("#links").append(links);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't have data for the formTemplate. I tried your proposition but it's doesn't work as well.
I really often get the error "n is undefined from underscore-min.js" and with your code I have "n.replace is not a function" 
Thank you again

Comment: With this option I don't get the form

Comment: @BoltMaud What version of underscore are you using? I assumed you're using the latest version. There was an API change, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/2333214

Comment: I have underscore 1.8.3 in a folder bower_component but the file bower.json doesn't have a dependencie for underscore and when I tried to add it with "bower install underscore", nothing is happened in this file. I think that it's strange.

Comment: @BoltMaud Probably because of the `this` context inside `when` success. See the updated in answer. If that doesn't fix it, use un-minified version of underscore and check the actual error

Comment: Still don't work.. :( with 1.5.2 version (I added "underscore" in bower.json file and update and it install this version)

Comment: @BoltMaud You need to use the syntax corresponding to the underscore version you're using... BTW you can specify a version in `bower.json`